# Override express route handler

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to redefine a express route handler

I have something like

```
var x = {
    handle: function(req, res){
        res.send("first");
    }
}
app.post("/handle", x.handle);

setTimeout(function(){
    x.handle = function(req, res){
        res.send("second");
    }
}, 2000)
```

but this doesn't change the way that route handles requests. 
How can I achieve something like this?

Comment: Could you try `app.post("/handle", () => x.handle );` i.e. have the attached handler ask for `x.handle` each time it is called?

Comment: that doesn't work at all

Comment: You need to pass both params, `(req, res) => x.handle(req, res)`.

Comment: thanks. now it works just fine

Comment: Will post this as an answer then.

Answer (score 2):

A simplest fix is to ensure `x.handle` is **always** retrieved. In your approach, the function reference is retrieved once, when you attach it but then when you set the reference to point to another function, the post handler still points to the old one.

Attach then

```
app.post("/handle", (req, res) => x.handle(req, res) );
```

This method always asks `x` for current value of the `handle` method and you are free to reattach it to anything you want.

Answer (score 0):

### why it doesn't work

when you pass `x.handle` into a method, as a callback, you are not passing a reference to `x` at all. you are only passing `handle` around.

later, when you change `x.handle`, you are changing the `handle` method for `x` as expected. but, the previous reference to `x.handle` as a parameter to your post method is unchanged, because this call to post knows nothing about `x`. it only knows about the `handle` method that you passed in.

### how to fix it

there are a lot of ways to fix this, depending on how you really want to handle things.

if you just need a timeout, then something like this would work:

```
var count = 1;
app.post("/handle", function(req, res){

  if (count === 1){
    setTimeout(function(){
      count += 1;
    }, 2000);
    // do the first thing here
  } else {
    // do the second thing here
  }  

});
```

if you don't need the timeout, you could just increment the `count`

again, there are a lot of ways to do this... but you will have to include the logic of deciding which one to do, inside of the route handler function directly.